# Meta viewport not scaling website on iPad

Tags: html, ipad, safari, viewport

I have a (rather simple) website that I wish to automatically scale and adjust such that the main content area fits in the screen without horizontal scrolling on iPad. On Landscape mode it works fine, however on portrait mode it leaves out part of it on the side, and the user has to scroll horizontally.
It normally works fine for other websites I did, but for this one I can't understand what is stopping Safari from doing this.

I added the following line at the top of the HTML but it doesn't seem to have any effect (I tried various alternatives like adding the `initial-scale=1.0` etc. too)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

What could be the reason this is not working?

**Clarification**

I am not looking for a media query solution. I am just trying to understand why for some sites the iPad (and other touch devices) automatically scale down a website to fit on screen, while in this case something is causing it not to. I am just trying to identify the reason for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. iPad (and most touch devices) actually scale the website automatically, without the need of the `<meta name="viewport" ... >` if the website is not explicitly designed to be responsive.

However, this scaling does not seem to work when the website is too wide. My content was 1024px wide, which for some reason was triggering the devices to turn off scaling.

I changed the content's width to 960px (I don't know the actual threshold, but my other site that scales well had this width) and the issue was immediately fixed.

Adding this answer in case someone is looking for a reason why scaling is not working on his site.

Obviously this is not related to having a responsive site, this is just when the website is simple and scaling is enough.

Answer (score 2):

there is fixed width given for inner container

```
div#branding{
 width: 1024px;
}

#content{
 width: 1024px;
}

div#footer{
 width: 1024px;
}
```

change all the 3 `width` to `100%` for @media screen

more information on @media screens can be found [here](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/)

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    div#branding {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #content {
        width: 100%;
    }
    div#footer {
        height: 40px; /* remove height */
        display: inline-block; /* change display:block to display: inline-block; */
    }
}
```

and it will work

the right side footer content will come down as the left side content is more

[**screenshot**](http://s29.postimg.org/9zyjlgyfr/demo.png)

note : your footer will broke as fixed height is given you can remove it

for fixing your footer change css for footer

```
div#footer {
 height: 40px; /* remove height */
 display: inline-block; /* change display:block to display: inline-block; */
}
```

[**screenshot**](http://s21.postimg.org/goahrddyv/demo2.png)

Comment: If I do `width: 100%` on `#branding`, `#content` and `#footer` they won't be centred any more on normal desktop screens, which I don't want to. However, what I am trying to understand is what makes the iPad scale a website in some cases, and what makes it not scale in other cases. For example in this case, another site I did with exactly the same layout (centred header, all simple) iPad resizes it fine: http://www.bounce-life-coaching.com

Comment: forgot to add `@media screens`

Comment: This answer was actually closest to the real problem since for some stupid reason it was the width of 1024px that was  causing the page not being scaled, while with a lower width (I used 960px) scaling kicked in again. Your solution works too, or rather avoids the issue by using media queries. (although the footer would need to be adjusted)

Answer (score 1):

I used width:100% and it solves my orientation layout situations, but there seems to be media queries that can help too:

```css
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Portrait styles */
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Landscape styles */
}
```

Check this site out for more: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-use-css3-orientation-media-queries/

Let us know if it works out.

Comment: On which element did you put `width: 100%` ? I already have it on my `body` tag.

Comment: I am using normalize (https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), and for everything that I need to have full width of the browser on, I use width:100%. The %s work great with all the devices I tested on. Did the @media queries help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on rules you got in your CSS you will need to assign portrait mode such as landscape or portrait and add desired width also.

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) and (max-width:1024px){
    some rules that will be applied to iPad in landscape mode
}
```

And big big difference is this, which will be applied on all 1024px screens

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    some css rules for "normal" screens on max-width: 1024px
}
```

EDIT:
So make sure that you put your "container" divs on 100% in various modes and adjust all other elements. the scrollbar you got is actually DOM element with fixed div or margins and paddings that affect width of whole page

Answer (score 0):

I think the meta tag has a minimum scale besides the maximum:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

What I don't know is if it will make any difference at this point.

It should work in theory, along with:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    /* landscape */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    /* portrait */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'm noticing is that Safari by default scales the web page automatically. However if the user manually applies some scaling - Safari stops its automatic scaling.
In my case this was the reason why it scaled some sites and others don't.